# Virtual functions and vector iterator

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with this specific piece of code:
It seems like virtual functions don't work as I expected.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class CPolygon
{
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    CPolygon()
    {
        this->name = "Polygon";
    }
    virtual void Print()
    {
        printf("From CPolygon: %s\n", this->name.c_str());
    }
};

class CRectangle: public CPolygon
{
public:
    CRectangle()
    {
        this->name = "Rectangle";
    }
    virtual void Print()
    {
        printf("From CRectangle: %s\n", this->name.c_str());
    }
};

class CTriangle: public CPolygon
{
public:
    CTriangle()
    {
        this->name = "Triangle";
    }
    virtual void Print()
    {
        printf("From CTriangle: %s\n", this->name.c_str());
    }
};

int main()
{
    CRectangle rect;
    CTriangle trgl;
    std::vector< CPolygon > polygons;
    polygons.push_back( rect );
    polygons.push_back( trgl );

    for (std::vector<CPolygon>::iterator it = polygons.begin() ; it != polygons.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->Print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expected to see:

```
From CRectangle: Rectangle
From CTriangle: Triangle
```

instead I get:

```
From CPolygon: Rectangle
From CPolygon: Triangle
```

Is this expected behavior? How should I call Print() function to get output expected by me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior? How should I call Print() function to get output expected by me?

Yes, it is expected behavior.

The problem is that standard containers, including `vector`, have *value semantics*: they store *copies* of the objects you pass to `push_back()`. Polymorphism, on the other hand, is based on *reference semantics* - it requires references or pointers in order to work correctly.

What happens in your case is that your `CPolygon` object gets [*sliced*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), which is not what you want. You should store *pointers* (possibly smart pointers) in your vector rather than objects of type `CPolygon`.

This is how you should rewrite your `main()` function:

```
#include <memory> // For std::shared_ptr

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<CPolygon> > polygons;
    polygons.push_back( std::make_shared<CRectangle>() );
    polygons.push_back( std::make_shared<CTriangle>() );

    for (auto it = polygons.begin() ; it != polygons.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->Print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e1835d348efba8d0997a168aa9990f29-9e84fdc2d22f4cab4cc066ed54711a46).

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I also tried example with standard pointers, worked as well.

Comment: what is shared_ptr<> and auto?[beginner]

Comment: @Dineshkumar: That's a broad topic, I suggest you ask a new question (no, two new questions!) on StackOverflow :) (but don't forget to do some research first, the answers may be there already)